# Generator of direct product of modules is direct product of each generator?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let assume I have an R-module M over a ring $R$ with unit and I want to consider the direct product (or direct sum, since I understand that they are both the same when the product has finitely many factors) $M \oplus M$. Furthermore, let $N_1 \oplus N_2 \subseteq M \oplus M$ be a submodule in $M \oplus M$ which is generated by
\begin{align*} \left\langle \begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ b_1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} a_2 \\ b_2\end{pmatrix} \right\rangle , a_i, b_i \in M \end{align*}
and lets assume I want to understand the structure of this submodule. My question is: Can I instead study the generator
\begin{align*} \left\langle  a_1 , a_2 \right\rangle\oplus \left\langle  b_1 , b_2 \right\rangle , \end{align*}
and is it true that
\begin{align*} N_1 \oplus N_2 = \left\langle  a_1 , a_2 \right\rangle\oplus \left\langle  b_1 , b_2 \right\rangle. \end{align*}

Sorry if this is a stupid question but I am not very familiar with these concepts. Thank you in advance!

EDIT: My intuition tells me that this is not possible. And if you know helpful literature regarding this topic and tell me some of them, it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true take :

$M=\mathbb{Z}$ , $N_1=0, N_2=M$ . then $0 \oplus \mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ now take  : \begin{align*} S= \left\langle \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} \right\rangle \end{align*} $S$ is isomorphic to $0 \oplus \mathbb{Z}$  . in fact $0 \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to  $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $S=\left\langle  (1 , 1) \right\rangle$ via the map : $x\rightarrow (x,x)$ .

Now do we have : \begin{align*} 0 \oplus \mathbb{Z} = \left\langle  0 , 1 \right\rangle\oplus \left\langle  0 , 1 \right\rangle. \end{align*}
The answer is obviously a no, since if we had this, then $\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ which is not true.